# Using "of/about" after the word "review"

Tags: prepositions

> a systematic review and meta analysis of consent in clinical trials

or

> a systematic review and meta analysis about consent in clinical trials

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

To say "a review about something" is not wrong, but is non-idiomatic and may sound strange or jarring in some contexts. It means the review covers topics and materials related to that something. It can occur in such a sentence as:

> What is the review about?
>
> It is about the grammar book that came out last year.

"A review of" sounds more idiomatic and suitable for most cases.

> a systematic review **of** consent in clinical trials

This sentence tells you that what is being reviewed is strictly *consent in clinical trials*. You can also use "a review on".

> Here's a review on recent publications in film studies.

Comment: In this context I have only ever seen _of_.